# General solution to a simple ODE in Fourier transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While going through my notes on Fourier transform, I chanced upon an ODE.

The ODE is:
$$U_{yy}(\omega , y) - \omega^{2}U(\omega , y) = 0$$

The general solution is:
$$ Ae^{\omega y} + Be^{-\omega y}$$

However, in working out the general solution I've found, using the method of undetermined coefficient, to be

$$ Ae^{\omega } + Be^{-\omega}$$

I find it extremely perplexing the the general solution given by the text is correct. Could someone tell me have I missed out?

Comment: You just left out the independent variable $y$ since the ODE is on $y$, not $\omega$.  Here, $\omega$ is simply a parameter in the ODE $U_{yy}-\omega^2U=0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Could you explain further on what you meant by that I have left out "y"?
In using the Method of undetermined coefficient, I proceed to find the roots as usual using the quadratic formula.

Comment: The roots are indeed $\pm \omega$.  But the corresponding solution is the $Ae^{\omega y}+Be^{-\omega y}$.

Comment: The method of undetermined coefficient will help you if the ode is nonhomogeneous. In your case, the characteristic equation for the homogeneous problem is $r^2-\omega^2=0$

Comment: Ahh I see why. What was I thinking.

Comment: Sorry, it was probably a slip. Thanks for the reminder.